# Microsoft Standard CDN for some PoP servers URL Redirect is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, cdn, azure-cdn

Microsoft Standard CDN for some PoP servers URL Redirect is not working.

So far these are having issues: 
[2620:1ec:bdf::10] Dallas PoP, 
13.107.246.10   (New York)

the URL: http://live.sitename.com is not redirecting to https://www.sitename.ibdb.com other users using different PoP servers are not having the same issue, it works for them.

Only users that are using those two servers so far seems not to be working.

It is not the IIS Redirect rules as when the CDN is turned off it works for all users.

But, when using the CDN does not work for users in Dallas or New York.

Is anyone else having same or similar issue?

If so was you able to solve it and how?

Comment: Is the URL `http://live.sitename.com` your custom CDN endpoint? What do you mean "when the CDN is turned off it works for all users."? Could you describe it with more details?

Comment: 1. Yes, http://live.sitename.com is the custom CDN Endpoint.  2. When I switch my DNS records to point to the server directly and by pass the CDN it works for all users. But, when I have it pointing to the CDN it does not.